# Are there example certificates available for test purposes?

Tags: certificates

Are there example certificates (PEM format) for testing available somewhere ?
For test purposes I would need a certificate signed with SHAS256/ECDSA P-256, together with a complete chain to test verification.

Comment: https://www.cloudflare.com uses valid EV ECDSA certificates, you can download DER / PEM certificates using your browser and do the conversion using `openssl` if neccessary.

Comment: Maybe this should go to security.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the XCA tool. It allows creation of certificates.

Answer (score 0):

you can find some ECC certificates using crt.sh tool. For example DigiCert issues ECC certificates, if you narrow the search to this CA, you can manually search for certificates with P-256 curve.

Following filters searches for all certificates issued by DigiCert ECC Secure Server CA
https://crt.sh/?Identity=%25&iCAID=1516